# Android: How should I optimise this AIDL code & avoid race condition

Tags: java, android, android-service, aidl

I'm creating a media player app.

When I starts or resumes the application I want to check if the media player was already playing a song.

So that if it was I will set my Pause/Play `ToggleButton` to **Pause**, else it was not playing earlier then button will set to **Play**.

(i.e. for e.g. if the user was already using the media player and left the app by pressing home or back button & now he resumes the player. then the button should be configured correctly.)

The actual MediaPlayer object is implemented in the Service & all the communications are done via `AIDL interface` methods.

Right now,

1. In `onResume` I'm calling an `AsynTask method` that will check all
   the running services and check If my `MusicService` is also running.
2. If yes then I'm calling an `aidl method` to check if
   `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` is true or not.
3. If yes then the `toggleButton` will set to pause(i.e. currently
   playing), else play.

**Problem:**
This `AsyncTask` is creating a race condition. That is sometimes it runs as intended & sometimes it just throws error

Code:

```
// In onResume
protected void onResume() {
    new PlayerStatusCheck().execute();
}

//AsyncTask Class
class PlayerStatusCheck extends AsyncTask {
    boolean isServiceAvailable;
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (com.example.playingworking.MusicService.class.getName()
                    .equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        isServiceAvailable = isMyServiceRunning();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        try {
            if (!isServiceAvailable) {
                doInBackground(null);
            } else {
                if (aidlObject.isMediaPlaying()) {
                    tbPlayPause.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    tbPlayPause.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "MainActivity onPostExecute: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code In MusicService :**

```
//In IBinder onBind()
public boolean isMediaPlaying(){
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please Suggest...Thanks

Comment: What made you think it was a race condition? Which part has the race condition? I don't see any locks or synchronized blocks yet so I assume that the actual point of the race condition is somewhere else? Inside the service perhaps?

Comment: Umm...there is nothing much in the Service class. When I try to debug with breakpoints it does not give any error. I think by that time service gets started. I guess error is occurring in `isMyServiceRunning`